# Azure SDK StorageAccountUpdateParameters

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-sdk-python

Trying to write a Python script to update an Azure Storage Account so that only traffic from certain VNet subnets are allowed. I can toggle off access from all networks fine, but when I try and add an additional parameter to lock it down, I'm getting errors regardless of what syntax I use.

Working example :-

```
sa_params2 = storage_client.storage_accounts.update(group_name,storage_account_name,StorageAccountUpdateParameters(network_rule_set=NetworkRuleSet(default_action='Deny')))
```

Non-working example :-

```
sa_params1 = storage_client.storage_accounts.update(group_name,storage_account_name, 
                                                   StorageAccountUpdateParameters(network_rule_set=NetworkRuleSet(default_action='Deny', virtual_network_rules=VirtualNetworkRule([subnet_id], action='Allow'))))
```

I've tried various permutations and gone over and over the docs and I can't see the problem. The error I get is `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given`

Answer (score 0):

From a pure Python perspective, models in the SDK are always taking keyword only syntax, this is incorrect:

```
VirtualNetworkRule([subnet_id], action='Allow')
```

Also, based on the docstring of that class, the two parameters are "virtual_network_resource_id" as string, and action:

```
    :param virtual_network_resource_id: Required. Resource ID of a subnet, for example:
 /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{groupName}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/{vnetName}/subnets/{subnetName}.
:type virtual_network_resource_id: str
:ivar action: The action of virtual network rule. Default value: "Allow".
:vartype action: str
```

(I'm working at Microsoft on the Azure SDK for Python team)

Comment: I've already tried a string and had the same results. I guess what I'm looking for is an example of what this code should look like, I can't find it documented anywhere other than the SDK. I've written out what I believe is correct based on the docs, but it's obviously not right

Comment: ```sa_params1 = storage_client.storage_accounts.update(group_name,storage_account_name, 
                                                   StorageAccountUpdateParameters(network_rule_set=NetworkRuleSet(default_action='Deny',virtual_network_rules=VirtualNetworkRule(subnet_id, action='Allow'))))
```

Comment: You could create an issue asking for sample, that's a fair ask https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue. I wasn't interpreting the documentation correctly and the StorageAccountUpdateParameters should have been listed as a dictionary.

Comment: ```StorageAccountUpdateParameters({'parameter1' : 'value1'}, etc)```